# How to run script on SFTP login?

Tags: ssh

I created a two-factor auth script for SSH, that uses ForceCommand in the ssh config. How can I disable that for SFTP logins, or even better, how to run a script before entering the SFTP shell?

Comment: Maybe the easiest way would be to have another, low privileged user with a null shell?

Comment: How would I access my files though?

Comment: You would use SSH and the ssh user in order to use the shell, and use sftp/scp as the other user in order to access files.